# PHP Compare a difference of timestamp and a real time

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to compare a difference between two timestamps and a time in base 60 or 10.
More precisely if timestamp1-timestamp2 is longer (or no) than x hours and y seconds.

I'm using DateTime and DateInterval classes, but there isn't such a function, and i don't find a clean solution.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have examples of your `timestamp1` and `timestamp2` data?

Comment: $remainingTimeBeforeReceipt = $TempReceiptDateTime->getTimestamp()-$ShipDateTime->getTimestamp()

Comment: There is such functions in `DateTime` and `DateInterval`. See my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$time1 = new DateTime("2011-01-26 01:13:30"); // string date
$time2 = new DateTime();
$time2->setTimestamp(1327560334); // timestamps,  it can be string date too.
$interval =  $time2->diff($time1);
echo $interval->format("%H hours %i minutes %s seconds");
```

Output

```
11 hours 32 minutes 4 seconds
```

Comment: +1 for using DateTime and DateInterval, the only way to determine the number of hours correctly (and that takes into account DST changes too)

Answer (score 2):

```
$timestamp1 = strtotime('2012-01-26 14:00:00');
$timestamp2 = strtotime('2012-01-25 17:00:00');

if (abs($timestamp1 - $timestamp2) < 60 * 60 * 5 /* (5 hours) */) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert both the timestamp and the real time to the UNIX timestamp. Then simply subtract to get the number of seconds difference.

Answer (score 0):

With datetime objects:

```
$interval = $TempReceiptDateTime->diff($ShipDateTime);
echo $interval->format('%R%H:%I:%s days');
```

[more](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)